# PHP как получить файл без изменения

Tags: php, java, разработка-игр

Суть в том что я делаю свою игру на `Java` и решил сделать тестовый мультиплеер.

Но повозившись со скриптом на сервере обнаружил что клиенту(игры) не получается обойти исключение которое я добавил чтоб левые люди не могли получить файл:

```
if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK'))` `die("Forbidden to you =)");
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтоб на программу это исключение не действовало, но чтоб левые люди не заходили?

Comment: Давайте определимся что у вас получается: Клиент(на `JAVA` который) обращается к серверу(на `PHP`) за данными. Мне такая схема видится так: ваша игра это лишь `визуальное` оформление игры, вся логика, все вычисления должны быть на сервере(`PHP`). Касаясь вашего вопроса: Чтобы каждый левый не получал доступ а только авторизованный, нужно при авторизации давать ключ и только по нему сервер будет отвечать (это не гарантия безопасности, но вы легко можете узнать кто играется с вашими апихами). При такой схеме волноваться не о чем.

Comment: Пусть хацкеры лезут, на игру повлиять не смогут. Вы должны понять, что вы не скроете свой сервер от левых глаз, если приложение взаимодействует с чем-то, то должны понимать, что и челвоек сможет влезать в этот обмен. Если у вас логика(всякие расчеты) выполняет клиент, то это уже дырка - такого не должно быть, надо это исправить и не будет проблем.

Comment: Обычно это решается через `SAPI` или `API` сервисы, специальные для программы, которая будет знать доступ для подключения и проведения необходимых операций. Либо делать на единую точку входа с авторизацией к примеру. Можно даже сделать специальные заголовки и юзерагент, чтобы только программа могла обращаться к адресу - правда их можно подменять откуда угодно, по этому не лучший выход.